# How to run a iOS 5/ARC project on iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

If I create a new iOS 5 project using one of XCode's templates and use ARC and set the deployment target to 4.3 and then try to run it on an iPhone (which is provisioned) which has iOS 4.3.1 installed then I get the following message:

"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

I'm not making any changes, this is with an unaltered template project.

ARC is compile time and from my searching previous posts it should be backward compatible and run, I must be missing some setting in Xcode to enable it to run on the 4.3 device?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding the armv6 architecture to your project (Project>Build Settings>Architectures)

Comment: ARMV6 is for iPhone (2G and 3G) only - the former ends at iOS 3.1.3, the latter at 4.2.1 -> no need for ARMV6 at all when targeting iOS 4.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the deployment target of the "target" rather than the "project". Do that in the build settings. The setting set at the target level takes precedence over the one set at the project level so maybe you still have 5.0 set at the target.

Otherwise, what you've done should work and you're right that ARC makes no difference to this (although remember you can't use weak references before iOS 5).

Comment: What should one do to work-around / deal with any weak references?

Comment: Just don't use them basically. A weak reference is just an `assign` property which doesn't get nilled out when the referenced object is deallocated. It's not a problem, you just need to be aware and code effectively.